# jQuery-ui resizable not working on Marionette.ItemViem

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, marionette, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to make an application where the user will be able to click and drag inside an area to create rectangles. The catch is that the area is a `Marionette.CollectionView` and the user by dragging and releasing the mouse button is creating a new `Rectangle model`, that gets added to the collection (which takes care of rendering it).

Here's the itemView's code

```
var RectangleView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "<div> </div>",
  className: "rectangle",
  events: {},


  initialize: function(){
    this.$el.draggable({
      containment: 'parent'
    });
    this.$el.resizable();
    this.setCssStyle();
  },

  setCssStyle: function (options) {
    that = this;
    this.$el.css({
      'width': that.options.width + 'px',
      'height': that.options.height + 'px',
      'top': that.options.top + 'px',
      'left': that.options.left + 'px',
      'border': '1px solid black',
      'position': 'absolute'
    });
  }

});
```

Within the `initialize` method I set the view's element to be `draggable` and `resizable`. While draggable works fine, resizable doesn't work at all. (I am also including the necessary jquery-ui.css file)

The above ItemView gets appended as soon as I add the model to the CollectionView (which happens on a custom event of my CollectionView) here's the code for the CollectionView

```
var ScreenView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  template: "<div>  </div>",
  className:"screen",
  itemView: RectangleView,
  events: {
    'boxmakerstoppeddrawing' : 'drawingHandler'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.$el.boxMaker(); 

  },

  itemViewOptions: function() {
    return boxProperties;
  },


  drawingHandler: function() {
    var rectangle = new Rectangle();
    this.collection.add(rectangle);
  }
});
```

Any ideas of what I could be doing wrong, causing the .resizable not to work?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me!
As i was told by user seutje in the #jquery irc.freenode channel, I should attach the jquery-ui methods `onRender` instead of initialization

```
  initialize: function(){
    this.setCssStyle();
  },

  onRender: function(){
    this.$el.draggable({
      containment: 'parent'
    });
    this.$el.resizable();
  }
```

Everything works now, but I would like  feedback whether this is optimal. 
Considering that I'm attaching methods `onRender`, during resize the `ItemView` gets re-rendered, therefore  while `onRender` gets called whenever I resize the item and as a result re-attaches .draggable and .resizable?